# Docker - port forwarding

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I'm need help, can not connect to the container all day. I used this address: 127.0.0.1:80 and see: http://joxi.ru/Vm6oegWtxoQVK2. When enter this command 'docker ps' I see it:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
42941a9e0dda        docker_web          "python manage.py ru…"   45 seconds ago      Up 4 seconds        127.0.0.1:8000->80/tcp   docker_web_1
```

Docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: /django.testsite/Dockerfile
  ports:
    - "127.0.0.1:8000:80"
```

Docerfile

```
FROM python:3

RUN easy_install pip
RUN pip install django==1.9.12
RUN pip install requests

ADD . /.
WORKDIR /django.testsite

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "127.0.0.1:80"]
```

How solve?

Comment: Common dude or dudette, read the docker ps >> 127.0.0.1:8000

Answer (score 4):

In your `docker-compose.yml` file, you specify `"127.0.0.1:8000:80"` as the port mapping. This means that you are mapping port 8000 on your local ip, 127.0.0.1, to port 80 on the internal container.

Docker also reinforces this in the `docker ps` call, where it tells you that the container has a port mapping with `127.0.0.1:8000->80/tcp`.

If you visit `127.0.0.1:80`, there is nothing hosted on that port. You need to visit `127.0.0.1:8000` instead.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, but problem is reproduced, if visit to 127.0.0.1:8000 and change СMD to 127.0.0.1:80. I not understand what doing wrong

Comment: Do not change the command. Your configuration is correct as is, you just need to visit 127.0.0.1:8000. Docker has an internal network that containers use. Your container binds to port 80 on its internal network, and your network configuration redirects your host port 8000 to the docker container's internal port of 80.

Comment: I'd highly recommend reading this article to understand the configuration that you are running https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/docker-networking-rules/